# Python: Hardware Timer or Software Timing Only?

Tags: python, time, timer, timeout

I wish to know if there exist a hardware timer library in python that is a timer that expires after a given period and cause an interrupt instead of the time.time method which basically polls for time.

```
#Check for Timer(Time)
#Timed Out -> Cause an Interrupt
#ISR Code: Return Value
```

Comment: you can use the `signal` module

Comment: I'm on windows ..so simply I can't . signal.alarm is not available